# Фоновый ввод информации C++

Tags: c++

**Как сделать так чтобы программа работала, скажем циклом, но ждала ввода информации?** Допустим у нас есть бесконечный цикл, который перечисляет цифры в порядке возрастания. Он работает и бесконечно крутит цифры, до того момента, когда пользователь не напишет стоп. Как это сделать и возможно ли это в консольном приложении?

Comment: `while(true){ cin >> s; do_smth();}` пойдёт?

Comment: cin останавливает программу и ждет ввода. Мне нужно чтобы программа работала и ждала ввода одновременно.

Comment: многопоточность?

Comment: нет, это не то что мне нужно

Comment: не уверен что возможно переносимое решение, аналогичный вопрос на основном SO - [Non-blocking console input C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171132/non-blocking-console-input-c)

Comment: я думаю, можно запустить асинхронное чтение из stdin и повесить на это чтение коллбек.

Comment: Можно и не асинхронное - достаточно делать неблокирующий read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо. Это решение выводит числа, пока не будет нажата какая-либо клавиша клавиатуры. В данной задаче очень полезен метод `kbhit()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i<1000000; i++)
        {
            if (kbhit()) {
                run = false;
                break;
            }
            cout << i << "\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если Вам необходимо, чтобы юзер ввёл именно слово "стоп", то моё решение, к сожалению, Вам категорически не подходит...

Comment: если что, это не переносимое решение...

Comment: так, код работает как надо, так даже намного удобнее. Спасибо за хоть какое либо решение задачи, буду рыть глубже, создавать команды типа "стоп". Но вы дали хороший старт, теперь я по крайней мере знаю что решение существует. Еще раз спасибо