# Неблокирующая функция для получения строки из stdin на Си

Tags: linux, c

Собственно вопрос в заголовке
Нужна какая-то неблокирующая функция для получения строки, которую ввел пользователь в терминале. Если пользователь еще не нажал на энтер - то возвращается что-то вроде -1

Comment: Ваш вопрос изначально содержит противоречие. Если речь идёт о **строке**, то она появляется только **после нажатия** на клавишу Enter. До этого строки просто нет. Есть введённые **символы**. А каждый символ (если спускаться ещё ниже) - два события: нажатие на клавишу + отпускание клавиши. Если это Вас устроит, рекомендую использовать библиотеку ncurses. Там есть соответствующие средства.

Comment: Можно использовать библиотеку readline , там есть возможность считывать по символьно.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786175/240512